# 2-D Array Slicing without NumPy Import

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm learning how to work through 2-D arrays and am currently trying to figure out how to do this without the numPy import. A simple 1-D array could be sliced accordingly:

```
Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Array[start:stop:step]
```

But what if the array were to be instead:

```
Array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I see that I can slice certain elements contained in the lists of the list like:

```
Array2[0][1]
2
```

However, what would be a possible method of slicing say elements 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 (or whichever values) while they are still contained in their respective lists.

Comment: MAY BE you need to revise your example (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9). those values can not be sliced out even using  numpy! of course you can do that in some way, but I mean you can't do that by just sth like `array[x:y, m:n]`

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to index nested lists the way that you want. However, you can achieve the effect of flattening the list (returning a single list, we'll call Array3) then indexing appropriately.

```
Array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Array3 = [item for sublist in Array2 for item in sublist]
Array3[2:]
>>>> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For more info, see [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)